# When fetching data from table "add_hotels" but along with the required data i'm also getting some NULL arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**It is the result function inside the HotelController.**

```
public function result()
    {
        $data=Input::except(array('_token'));

            $city= $data['city'];
            $cities_id = DB::table('cities')
                  ->select('id')
                  ->where('cities.city_name', 'LIKE', "%$city%")
                  ->get();

            $hotel = array();
            foreach ($cities_id as $value) {
              $i=$value->id;

              $hotel[] = DB::table('add_hotels')
                  ->select('id')
                  ->where('city_id', '=', $i)
                  ->get();
            }
            var_dump($hotel);
            exit();
            return view('hotel.result',compact('hotel','city'));

    }
```

This is the result which i'm getting, but I required only data marked by red color box

[image]

Comment: please see the attached Image for better understanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$cities_id = DB::table('cities')
              ->where('cities.city_name', 'LIKE', "%$city%")
              ->Join('add_hotels','add_hotels.city_id','=','cities.id')
              ->select('add_hotels.id')
              ->get();

var_dump($cities_id);
```